# Why does my 2017 Macbook Pro 13" 4 thunderbolt "Battery Level" in rapidly jump from 25% to 100%?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

12 months ago, I replaced the battery in my 2017 13" MBP with Touchbar 4 thunderbolt. I replaced it with the NewerTech battery from OWC/Macsales.com. It was reporting that it needed to be replaced and barely kept a charge.

It is again having charge issues (although the battery health claims to be "Normal"). When first installed, I'd easily get 6+ hours of usage on the laptop. Now, I'm lucky to get 3 hours.

Things I've tried:

- resetting the SMC
- Disabled "manage battery longevity"
- Allowing the battery to charge to 100%, Drain to 0% (automatic shutoff) - let sit for 5 hours. Re-charge to 100%, and let it charge for 3 hours.

This has not materially improved the battery performance.

I have noticed something strange - the "Battery Level" in "Usage History" will jump from ~25% to 100% when charging. I wonder if the battery really only has ~30% of its capacity, despite MacOS thinking it has more.

[image: System Preferences -> Battery -> Usage History 25% to 100% immediate jump]

Does anyone have any idea whats going on? I'm worried that the laptop itself is damaged and damages batteries, or if I've just gotten really unlucky.

[image: About this Mac]

[image: System Report -> Battery Information]

Comment: Sounds like a battery with a bad cell or cells.

Comment: Have you noticed that the battery just drops from 100% to ~30% and then gradually wears out or does it just go down in a regular slope (about)?

Comment: Yes, I'd look to OWC for redress.

Comment: @Thinkr - it’ll start dropping drastically after 60%. For example, from 60% to 50% in 5 minutes.

Comment: Alright, I would then be inclined to think that there's a problem with the battery. According to what you say, it has actually between 30% and 40% actual life. I think it might be good to include your comment (saying it's dropping from 60%) in the question as well as a screenshot of it. (Nice question! +1!)